# C Program to Count Lines of Code

Tags: c, line, counter, lines-of-code

I'm writing a simple LOC counter in C to count how many lines of code are in my C source files.  It's meant to be run from the command line, redirecting the target file as input and seeing a total line count printed to standard out. For example:

```
  counter.exe < counter.c
  15
```

So far the only rules I'm using are:

1. Only count lines that have more than 3 characters (no blank lines or lines that only have a closing brace and semi-colon, etc).
2. Don't count spaces as characters.

Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int input;
    int linecount = 0;
    int charcount = 0;

    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (input == ' ') {
        }
        else if (input == '\n') {
            if (charcount > 3) {
               linecount++;
            }
            charcount = 0;
        }
        else {
            charcount++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", linecount);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, can you offer some improvements to the rules to make this a more valid measure? Do people often count comments as valid lines of code? How about spaces or blank lines?

I don't want to start a debate over the validity of LOC counts in general, it's something I've been asked in several interviews and I think is worth knowing, in a general sense, how many lines of code my own projects are. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldnt worry so much about counting the lines of code, it is in my experience irrelevant. Something which counted the quality of code on the other hand...

Comment: I have to agree. You could even argue that a smaller line count is better, if it has the same functionality and is easy to understand by others. But again I'm interested in this because I was asked this during an interview question (how many lines of code would you say were in the largest project you've personally worked on?) I drew a blank, I really couldn't even come up with a guess. So this is a programming exercise and also just to get a deeper understanding of what a LOC count might be useful for. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a comment on the code itself: if you find yourself writing an empty if statement, this means there is usually a better way to structure your if's. Ex.

`if (input == '\n') {

    ...

} else if (input != ' ') {
    ...
}`

Comment: Do tabs count as regular characters?

Comment: hi, how to make the while loop'll exit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, people do:

- Count comments as LOC
- Count blank lines as LOC

However, people also assume/practice:

- Comments included are necessary/useful (not gratituitous)
- Blank lines are not excessive, and exist to provide clarity

Code line counters, as a result, generally take into account all line breaks in their computation.

Comment: +1 for "Comments included are necessary/useful (not gratituitous)"

Answer (score 6):

Don't write a program. Use `wc --lines`

Comment: @Raveline: So will OP's program.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing this more as a programming exercise though.  I agree, normally an existing tool would be preferred.

Comment: Combine with variations of `grep -v` to skip blank lines, short lines, and comments as desired.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this was a programming example, but if you want to use a windows command line I found [this](http://brett.batie.com/scripting/count-number-of-lines-in-a-file-using-dos/).

Which lead to:

```
findstr /R /N "^" *.h *.c | find /C ":"
```

Counts all lines in .h and .c files.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I came from a different development style than kvista, but we counted lines of code and comments separately.  We expected that the comments would be a certain percentage of the total lines (comments + code).  We didn't count blank lines at all.

If you're looking for a bit of a programming challenge, you can measure the [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) (or conditional complexity) of your C programs.

Answer (score 0):

Make a schedule of how long it will take you to write and debug the application.  Note the ending date.

Spend some time searching the web for tools such as:
http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html

Take the remaining time in your schedule and go on vacation. :-)

Otherwise the task becomes monstrous.  Such as parsing comments.  Defining a line (and how many statements or tokens are on a line).  Are blank lines counted?

Save your precious time for other projects.  Use existing tools.